# ElasticSearch ngram limitations

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, n-gram

What's the best practice for pattern searches? I have implemented using ngram tokenizer, however there are min and max limitations. For instance

min_gram - 3 and max_gram - 4 will limit the search to 3 characters and a max of 4 characters. like,

***abc*** will produce hits (if any) and ***abcd*** will produce hits (if any)
If I type ***abcde*** then I won't have any hits.

Because the tokenizer is going to create tokens ranging from 3-4 chars in length.  If I use the ***deprecated*** min and max with a larger difference, the index sizes will bloat.

The use case I am trying to solve is a scaleable pattern search which can accommodate any string length.

What's a solution for this. I came across suggestions to create multiple indices and "alias" them. Not sure what that does to the performance and how it can be used to scale for all of the use cases. Can someone suggest a solution?